# Interpolation with na.approx : How does it do that?

Tags: r, interpolation, zoo

I am doing some light un-suppression of employment data, and I stumbled on na.approx approach in the zoo package. The data represents the percentage of total government employment, and I figured a rough estimate would be to look at the trends of change between state and local government. They should add to one.

```
        State % Local %
2001    na  na
2002    na  na
2003    na  na
2004    0.118147539 0.881852461
2005    0.114500321 0.885499679
2006    0.117247083 0.882752917
2007    0.116841331 0.883158669
```

I use the spline setting which allows the estimation of leading na's

```
z <- zoo(DF2,1:7)    
d<-na.spline(z,na.rm=FALSE,maxgap=Inf)
```

Which gives the output:

```
State % Local %
0.262918013 0.737081987
0.182809891 0.817190109
0.137735231 0.862264769
0.118147539 0.881852461
0.114500321 0.885499679
0.117247083 0.882752917
0.116841331 0.883158669
```

Great right? The part that amazes me is that, the approximated na values sum to 1 (which is what I want, but unexpected!) but the documentation for na.approx says that it does each column separately, column-wise. Am I missing something? My money's on mis-reading the documentation

Comment: I would be worried more about if such large estimates are sensible. Given that you only have values on 1 side of your `NA` s, you are actually extrapolating rather than interpolating, which according to the `spline` documentation makes little sense for the default spline method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's just a chance property of linear least squares. The slopes of from both regressions sum to zero, as a result of the constraint that the sum of the series equals one; and the intercepts sum to one. Hence the fitted values from both regressions at any point in time sum to one.

EDIT: A bit more explanations.
y1 = a + beta * t + epsilon
y2 = 1-y1 = (1-a) + (- beta) * t - epsilon
Therefore, running OLS will give intercepts summing to one, and slopes to zero.

Comment: That's correct except there are also quadratic and cubic terms. The coefficients of the linear, quadratic and cubic terms for the second column are the negative of the corresponding terms of the first column (just as you have written for the linear term).